# Errors when a destructor deletes an array

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

```
class Celda
{
private:
    int* bloques_;
public:
    Celda(int size);
    ~Celda(){ delete [] bloques_; };
};
Celda :: Celda(int size)
{
    bloques_ = new int[size];
    bloq_ocupados_ = 0;
    tam_ = size;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tam_ ; ++i){
        bloques_[i] = 0;
    }
}

Tabla :: Tabla(int numcel, int tambloq)
{
    nceldas_ = numcel; tam_bloque_ = tambloq;
    tabla_ = new Celda*[nceldas_];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nceldas_ ; ++i){
        tabla_[i] = new Celda(tam_bloque_);
}
    ocupadas_ = 0;
}

Tabla :: ~Tabla()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nceldas_ ; ++i){
        delete [] tabla_[i];
    }
    delete [] tabla_;
}
```

I have this coded now, 2 classes, Celda and Tabla, and when I run my program it puts at the end:

*** glibc detected: free(): invalidad pointer: 0x0000000002391338 ***

The debugger stop deleting bloques_ pointer too many times (like 30) calling the destructor I think.

What is my error??

Comment: The code lacks copy-ctor and copy assignment but all classes seem to own their resources. This is likely a bug if you ever assign or copy construct something and can be the cause of your invalid free. Impossible to answer without more code.

Comment: I can't copy more code because I can't edit and paste more... but the [] deletes are the fail I think...

Comment: Yes, of course they are. But you need to find out where those pointers go wrong and this is likely in a copy operation of the class and a resulting double free.

Comment: I suggest throwing this code away and using `std::vector<Celda>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uses of new/new[] must match the uses of delete/delete[].

The tabla_[i] are allocated with new but freed with delete[].

Change it to

```
 delete tabla_[i];
```

and it will work.